# Watch configuration file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-config

in current project *node-config* npm package is used to maintain node.js configuration.

The issue i have is that I need to watch the file which is used by *node-config*, but according to documentation watch possibility is removed from this package.

I tried to get the current used file from *node-config* package, but there is no such API.

Could you please advise what is the best way I should proceed with?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a maintainer of `node-config`. It no longer has file-watching functionality and there is no plans to add it. Using a different tool is recommended to handle values that change at run time.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks a lot for the answer, by different tool you mean another npm module?

Comment: @AlexanderCharkov Not necessarily an NPM module. Some use a "key/value storage service" like Consul: https://www.consul.io/ Products like this are designed make a read/write configuration available to an application which may be running multiple instances and multiple machines and needs to real-time access to changing values. I don't currently need this feature and would consider it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some workaround/solution I have found after digging into *config* module code. You can use *getConfigSources()* to get the configurations array, where the last element is the actual configuration

```
const arrayOfConfigs = config.util.getConfigSources()
const loadedConfigPath = arrayOfConfigs[arrayOfConfigs.length - 1].name
```

Now you can watch this file if you need.